# Cannot read property of 'ID parameter'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

This is my code of Router where i imported my cart.js model

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Product = require('../models/products');
var Cart = require('../models/cart'); 

router.get('/add-to-cart/:_id',(req,res,next)=>{
  const productID = req.params._id;
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

  Product.findById(productID,(err,product)=>{
    if(err){
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    cart.add(product, product.id);
    req.session.cart = cart;
    res.redirect('/');
  })  
})
```

This is My code for Cart.js

```
module.exports = function cart(oldCart){
   this.items = oldCart.items;
   this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty;
   this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice;

   this.add = function(item,id){
      var storedItem = this.items[id]; // Here is Problem
      if(!storedItem){
        storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
      }
      storedItem.qty++;
      storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
      this.totalQty++;
      this.totalPrice = storedItem.price;
   };

   this.generateArray = function(){
      var array = [];
      for (var id in this.items){
        array.push(this.items[id]);
      }
      return array;
   };
}
```

Error:

events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: **Cannot read property '5d9182475f539435e81a7bb9' of undefined**
at cart.add (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\models\cart.js:7:36)
at Product.findById (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\routes\routes.js:85:10)
at C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4589:16
at C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4323:12
at process.nextTick (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2805:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4591:13
at C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4323:12
at process.nextTick (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2805:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

See my Full code at: https://github.com/ma-9/E_com_NodeJS.git

Comment: please go through the SO post on how to ask a question..

Comment: When asking "Why is my code not working" the [actual code is pretty much required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Error messages alone tell us little. Please include the **smallest** necessary code in order to reproduce the problem. Then someone can actually help you.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for helping me, This is my first experience to StackOverflow

Comment: Needs more context. The error is basically telling you that `this.items` is `undefined`, which in turn likely means that `oldCart` is *probably* undefined. You need to show what inputs you are expecting, and the usage of the function in context. And please read the link in the comment. Linking to a full and possibly "large enough" listing of code externally goes against what that says. **Necessary Code within your question**.

Comment: @NeilLunn
[Check my Code](https://github.com/ma-9/E_com_NodeJS.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i see your code and i think you have made mistake in Cart.js file and also add-to-cart route.. I have fix the issue and make a pull request to you..

Updated Code

```
module.exports = function cart(oldCart) {
this.items = oldCart.items || {};
this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

this.add = function (item, id) {
    var storedItem = this.items[id];
    if (!storedItem) {
        storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
    }
    storedItem.qty++;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
    this.totalQty++;
    this.totalPrice = (oldCart.totalPrice || 0) + storedItem.price;
};

this.generateArray = function () {
    var array = [];
    for (var id in this.items) {
        array.push(this.items[id]);
    }
    return array;
};
```

And In Your Routes when you call cart.add(product,product.id)
instead of you have to call product._id

Answer (score 0):

i see you code, in this line `Product.findById(productID,(err,product)=>{` you call `findById` function from `product` module. but i see in this file only

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new schema({
    imagePath: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    // imagePath2: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    // imagePath3: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    // imagePath4: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    // imagePath5: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    name: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    desc: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required:true},
    price: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number, required:true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("DND - Products",productSchema);
```

You must define the functions you need in this section. EX: findById

Comment: Thanks for giving Your valuable time to resolve my problem,

but i'm still not clear that how can i define **findByID** function in Product Module while **findById** is already predefined method by mongoose(mongoDB)

Answer (score 0):

mongooes db store data with unique id And the key is _id

so edit it

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Product = require('../models/products');
var Cart = require('../models/cart'); 

router.get('/add-to-cart/:_id',(req,res,next)=>{
const productID = req.params._id;
var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

Product.findById(productID,(err,product)=>{
if(err){
  res.redirect('/');
}
cart.add(product, product._id);
req.session.cart = cart;
res.redirect('/');
})  
})
```

Comment: No it also gives error

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined
    at cart.add (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\models\cart.js:7:36)
    at Product.findById (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\routes\routes.js:85:10)
    at C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\E_com_App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4589:16

Comment: Unhandled 'error' event ^ TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined at cart.add